# How can I change the notification sound to a custom but non-default sound?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Ok, so the title isn't as clear as it probably could be, but here goes:

In the Facebook Messenger application you can click the profile/settings button (top right on latest version) and there is a menu option for "Notifications & Sounds".

In this sub-menu there is an option for "Notification Sound" which allows you to select the sound that will be played when you receive a new message.

This list appears to be a list of 'built-in sounds' with one exception... "Default ringtone (name of current SMS notificaiton sound)"

Basically what I am looking to do, is to change the notification sound to be different from my SMS message sound. (I actually used to have this working great somehow, but then my phone went for a repair and had factory reset).

The facebook app has a similar setting, but allows me to select from ALL my custom sounds. This is what I am hoping for.

Is it possible to get other sounds to be available in the list? How can I make it different from SMS notifications?

Samsung S7 Edge, Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add the desired tone to the `/sdcard/Notifications` directory (followed by a restart, possibly).

Alternately, you can install a file manager app such as ES File Explorer, which you can choose as the notification tone picker, instead of the default menu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, that app made it pretty easy to do and seems to be working as desired now.

Comment: "choose as the notification tone picker", how is this changed?

Comment: Do you need a rooted phone to access the `/sdcard/Notifications` directory?

Comment: @Empiromancer AFAIR no. I haven't checked recently (with Android Oreo).

Comment: Except the Messenger "Storage" permission, I had to permit also Facebook App Manager "Storage" access. Otherwise it did not work. (Phone: Honor 9)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to allow Messenger to access to your storage (in the permissions of the app)? I had the same problem as you. By allowing this to Messenger all custom songs were added to the list you're mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

In my Android Phone I do the following either for Messenger or Lite Messenger:

1. Swipe down from the top
2. Select your settings button
3. Select Sound
4. Select Advanced
5. Select "Default notification sound" or if you are wanting a different ringtone select "Phone ringtone"

Answer (score 0):

You are right. I went to the Configurations, then Applications (or Apps), then Messenger, then click on Permissions. In Permissions select Storage. Then, when go back to Messenger notifications sound configuration, you"ll see the other ringtone sounds that you have in your cellphone ☝️

Answer (score 0):

This is probably kinda late and you've likely already figured this out, but in case somebody else is coming here looking for answers, I figured out how to do it on my Galaxy.

I'm not sure if it will be like this on other versions of Android and I have no clue how it would work on an iPhone, but here's what I did.

1. Go to settings
2. Tap "Apps"
3. Find Messenger in the list
4. Scroll down to the "App Settings" category
5. Tap "Notifications"
6. Under the Notifications sub-category, tap "Chats and calls" (not the little slider next to it, but the actual option itself)
7. Tap "Sound"
8. If you have another media app like Zedge installed, it'll ask you which you'd like to use to set the notification sound. If your notification is in your media storage, just click that, and scroll down and you should be able to find it.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple: Make a Directory on the phone called "Notifications" (if you dont have one) and copy your ringtone into it. It will then show up with all the Samsung ones.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejsUtt4FcJo